# Excel Formula Issue Using IF

Tags: excel

If E10='Dealer', Then SUM of D10=0;If E10=Customer, Then SUM of D10=B6/2

E10 is a drop down Menu. It has one other option of 'Pick One' that has no relevancy.

I'm not sure what I'm missing, or if I am able to set it up like this.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by _"Then SUM of D10=0;"_ do you want to set D10 equal to 0?  and also for _"SUM of D10=B6/2"_ do you want to set D10 equal to B6/2?

Comment: Yes. Basically if E10= Dealer, then I want D10 to be 0. If it was =Customer then I want it to be B6/2

Comment: Can you give us more info and try to be a little more descriptive, please?

Comment: E10 is a drop down menu.

It has two choices, Dealer, or Customer.

If Dealer is selected, I would like D10=0.
If Customer is selected, I would like D10=B6/2, or B6*.5 
(Half of B6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula *inside* `D10` because that is the cell you want to change.

```
=IF(E10="Dealer",0,IF(E10="Customer",B6/2,""))
```

When the Dropdown is at "Pick One" this formula will default to `""` (empty cell) you can change that to anything you want.